# What is the relation between Kubo's formula and the Green-Kubo relations?

Tags: non-equilibrium, transport-phenomena, quantum-transport

In one hand, [Kubo's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubo_formula) is used in linear response quantum mechanics to obtain response functions (conductivity, magnetic susceptibility, dielectric function) and so on in terms of correlation functions between an operator and the perturbation Hamiltonian (usually autocorrelations like current–current correlations in the case of the conductivity, see also Kubo-Greenwood formula). In the other hand, the [Green-Kubo relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%E2%80%93Kubo_relations) allow to determine other transport coefficients (like diffusion coefficient, viscosity, thermal conductivity, etc ) in terms of auto-correlation functions of derivatives of some operator.

Both look very similar, specially when you notice that Kubo's formula is used to get the electrical conductivity and the Green-Kubo relation is for the thermal conductivity.

What is exactly the link between the two? Can the Green-Kubo relations be derived from Kubo's formula? And if there is no direct link, where does the difference lie? Is it a classical-quantum distinction?